# Refreshing Only Favorites using Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, tridion, tridion-2011

I have a Data Extender in place that modifies the Favorites' titles when ever favorites are requested. But when I add a single favourite, only that item is updated without calling the whole list. My question is how do I refresh only the favorites part in Tridion using JavaScript so that the entire favorites list is retrieved and the list is run through my data extender so that the title is updated.

So How do I refresh favorites only in Tridion using JavaScript?

Comment: You may want to start using http://tridion.stackexchange.com for your Tridion-related questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$models.$cme.getShortcuts().getList().unload()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an instance open to test with, but in the PowerTools [AddUser](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/AddUser) tool I refresh the main list using:

```
$display.getView().refreshList();
```

I imagine you can pass a view name to the function to specify which view you want to refresh.

The source for the tool command is at

http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/AddUser/AddUserCommand.js